# Is $[JK:(x)][JK:(y,z)]\subseteq JK$ in $k[x,y,z]$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and $S=k[x,y,z]$. Let $m=(x,y,z)$ and $J,K\subseteq m$ be proper homogeneous ideals in $S$. Is this true that we always have:

$$[JK:(x)][JK:(y,z)]\subseteq JK \ ?$$

**Some background**: the case $K=m$ was asked at [Is $[Im:(x)][Im:(y,z)]\subseteq Im$ in $k[x,y,z]$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320951/is-imximy-z-subseteq-im-in-kx-y-z). It was not so hard. One can prove that the result holds if $J,K$ are monomial or if $K\subset m^2$ is integrally closed.    The statement is related to the question of whether the product of two ideals is Golod. See the preprint [Dao and De Stefani - On monomial Golod ideals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00806) for some partial results and why a modest monetary reward is offered for this frustrating problem (Question 4.6). My personal guess is that this is probably true in char. $0$.

Comment: Your equation only contains the product $JK$; the ideals $J$ and $K$ never appear separately. Is this intentional?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I am not sure what you meant. One can wrote, let $I=JK$, but being product is crucial for this property to have a hope of being true.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked up the paper now, and I see that you did mean what you wrote.